# I want to get city, country, state from Google Analytics object (GA object)

Tags: google-analytics

I want to get city, country and state from Google Analytic object only. I have set up client id and referrer.

```
ga(function(tracker) {  
  var client_id = tracker.get('clientId');  
  var referrer = tracker.get('referrer');

  console.log(client_id);
  console.log(referrer);
}
```

How can I get this from GA object?

Answer (score 2):

#### You can't.

Your client's IP is sent into GA, and they populate their reports with the best City/State/Country information they can determine for that IP address.